# How to get Facebook photo, full name, gender using Facebook SDK android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an Android application in which any Android user who is logging to Facebook using our Application, I need to extract his photo, his gender, his full name from the Facebook. I am using Facebook SDK for this.

With the help of Facebook SDK, I am able to login into Facebook but I am not sure how to extract his photo,gender and full name from the facebook?

Below is the code I am using to login into Facebook. I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#prerequisities)

```
public class SessionLoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

    private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    buttonLoginLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
    textInstructionsOrLink = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.instructionsOrLink);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback,
            savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    updateView();

    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Log.d("Hello", URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS + session.getAccessToken());
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ThesisProjectAndroid.class);
        startActivity(i);

    } else {
        Log.d("Hello", "Login Failed");
        textInstructionsOrLink.setText(R.string.instructions);
        buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.login);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickLogin();
        }
        });
    }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }
    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I need to make changes in the above class to get all the three information I needed. As far as I know If I am able to get facebook unique id for that person, I can get all the information I guess. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you looked at restfb/batchfb or perhaps scribe?  Once you are able to authenticate the user, you can retrieve the information quite easily (basic info is sent when a successful authentication is done - or you can retrieve via restfb by using the unique key)

Comment: what is restfb? Can you provide me any example?

Comment: you can check here: http://restfb.com/.  Once you have the user key, you can use it to retrieve the information associated with the user (provided the user has granted access to the app)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your `StatusCallback` function, you can get the details from the `GraphUser` object

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    private String fbAccessToken;

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            fbAccessToken = session.getAccessToken();
            // make request to get facebook user info
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.i("fb", "fb user: "+ user.toString());

                    String fbId = user.getId();
                    String fbAccessToken = fbAccessToken;
                    String fbName = user.getName();
                    String gender = user.asMap().get("gender").toString();
                    String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();

                    Log.i("fb", userProfile.getEmail());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. But i want to know how to get fetch the **email id** of the user. Do we need to give any extra permissions for that ??

Comment: This worked for me, but is now showing as deprecated.  Here's a post on Facebook that works as well, and with the String assignments from this example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize For the block of code, scroll down to the line "First, create a private method that requests the user's data:"

Comment: can we use that user's data into database?

Answer (score 33):

With new api and your custom button for facebook you can use below code:

put below gradle in your gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'

  Newer sdk does not need initializaion .

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(LoginActivity.this);//Is now depricated
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }
```

onActivityResult:

```
        @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         }
```

Button Click:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_f_sign_in_login:
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                    this,
                    Arrays.asList("user_friends", "email", "public_profile"));

            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            setFacebookData(loginResult);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        }
                    });
            break;
    }
}
```

setFacebookData:

```
     private void setFacebookData(final LoginResult loginResult)
       {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // Application code
                    try {
                        Log.i("Response",response.toString());

                        String email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                        String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                        String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                        String gender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");



                        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                        String id = profile.getId();
                        String link = profile.getLinkUri().toString();
                        Log.i("Link",link);
                        if (Profile.getCurrentProfile()!=null)
                        {
                            Log.i("Login", "ProfilePic" + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200));
                        }

                       Log.i("Login" + "Email", email);
                        Log.i("Login"+ "FirstName", firstName);
                        Log.i("Login" + "LastName", lastName);
                        Log.i("Login" + "Gender", gender);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,gender");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

get Facebook Friends Who has downoaded your app:

replace **parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name");**

with **parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,friends");**

Add below logic to get friends Data

```
                if (object.has("friends")) {
                  JSONObject friend = object.getJSONObject("friends");
                  JSONArray data = friend.getJSONArray("data");
                  for (int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                 Log.i("idddd",data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                  }
             }
```

Comment: Fb does not provide birthdate..please see my updated code

Comment: okay then update this line too parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,gender, birthday");

Comment: and what about user_friends

Comment: i didnt dig deep into that as i only need information for the person who login.This is parameter for permissions.There are another also like:"user_hometown", "user_location"...I didnt use user_friend permission but i just wrote it down to other let know that there are another permissions too.

Comment: @UmarAta gender key also not getting now.

Answer (score 6):

with new API

```
private void importFbProfilePhoto() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {

                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

                            if (me != null) {

                                String profileImageUrl = ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(me.optString("id"), 500, 500).toString();
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, profileImageUrl);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[See The following tutorials](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/personalize/)

You have to make a request to the get the GraphUser-Object. With this object you can get the informations you want: GraphUser `user.getName();` ,`user.getId();` etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Sdk v4.28 and for logged in Users as on question, it is easy as calling `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` inside (or after) success callback of `LoginManager`:

```
facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult{ 
                    //Profile.getCurrentProfile()
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                }
            });
```

You could use [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph), but doc itself says use above for logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

if you will get the null profile then use  Profile Tracker
 if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null)
            {

```
            mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                    // profile2 is the new profile
                    Log.d("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());
                    profile_firstname=profile2.getFirstName();
                    profile_lastname=profile2.getLastName();
                   // Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User ID : "+ profile2.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                }
            };

        }
```