# Facebook SDK for Android: how to get the user's gender

Tags: android, facebook

I suppose its either `getProperty("sex")` or `("gender")` or `user.asMap().get("sex")` or `("gender")` ?
also, what kind of permission do I set in the following line?

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email", "user_likes", "user_status"));
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542193/how-to-get-facebook-photo-full-name-gender-using-facebook-sdk-android?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no seperate permission for this this values you can get gender like this And see [THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/personalize)

```
   private String UserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {    

        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");              
        String Name =  user.getName();
        String Id =   user.getId();
        String lastname =    user.getLastName();
        String firstname =  user.getFirstName();
        String getUsername =  user.getUsername();             

        String get_gender = (String) user.getProperty("gender");


        String image_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture?type=square";        

        Log.i("User information == >", Name +Id + lastname+ 
                firstname + image_url + get_gender +  getUsername + "usermail"+User_mail  );

        text.setText(Name + "  mail = " +User_mail);

        return userInfo.toString();
    }
```

Comment: if I get the user image this way, does this remove the need to use com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView and use my own ImageButton for the user avatar instead?

Comment: Is email considered the username?

Comment: Could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275629/facebook-sdk-for-android-graphuser . Similar to this, but other permissions. I have tried, but have problems accessing the required details.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the gender of user from the **"user_about_me"** permission and get the gender from the response json by **user.getProperty("gender")                                .toString()**.

Comment: what? You don't that permission. I cite: `A person's name, profile picture, locale, age range and gender are included by default with the public_profile permission.`

Answer (score 1):

```
  Request.executeMeRequestAsync (session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {


            String fbId = user.getId();
            String fbAccessToken = fbAccessToken;
            String fbName = user.getName();
            String gender = user.asMap().get("gender").toString();       

            Log.i("FB", gender);
        }
    });
```